# What is the maximum file size for assets stored in Apigee API BaaS?

Tags: apigee, http-status-code-413

Looking at the [Apigee docs](http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/assets), there doesn't seem to be an indication of the maximum allowed file size for assets in API BaaS.

Currently I'm trying to POST a 39MB archive using the following CURL command:

```
curl -X PUT -i -F name="archive" -F file=@"/path/to/archive.zip" "https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/archives/{uuid}"
```

And it's throwing back:

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 98
Connection: Close

{
    "fault": 
    {
        "faultstring": "Body buffer overflow",
        "detail": 
        {
            "errorcode": "protocol.http.TooBigBody"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the request.streaming.enabled property on TargetEndpoint. This will bypass buffering in the message processor.

See: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/endpoint-properties-reference

Note: You'll also need to set response.streaming.enabled when you retrieve larger payloads.

Comment: This is occurring on the free/shared instance though, so I don't have the ability to manage the proxy directly.